# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 -> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, I have gotten to the point that this works:

**helloworld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hi" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I am using MacOS Mojave and for compilation I use the commands

```
>> g++ helloworld.cpp
>> ./a.out
```

This if working fine. Now I want to use header files. Therefore I've created the following files:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
   add(4,7);
   return 0;
}
```

**add.h**

```
#pragma once
int add(int a, int b);
```

**add.cpp**

```
#include "add.h"
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

and When I try to compile this I get:

```
>> g++ test.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "add(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-ebc106.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of just `g++ test.cpp`, try `g++ test.cpp add.cpp`

Comment: `g++ test.cpp add.cpp` worked!! @Ted -> that should have been `add(4,7)`

Comment: Ok, fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g++ test.cpp add.cpp
```

Every cpp file needs to be compiled to separate .obj files